# XLNetForSequenceClassification Pretrained model unable to load

Tags: nlp, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I tried loading the XLNet pretrained but this occurred. I've tried this before and it worked, however, now it doesn't. Any suggestion on how to fix this problem?

```
model = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("xlnet-large-cased", num_labels = 2)
model.to(device)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-d6f698a3714b> in <module>()
----> 1 model = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("xlnet-large-cased", num_labels = 2)
      2 model.to(device)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py in __init__(self, num_embeddings, embedding_dim, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse, _weight)
     95         self.scale_grad_by_freq = scale_grad_by_freq
     96         if _weight is None:
---> 97             self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(num_embeddings, embedding_dim))
     98             self.reset_parameters()
     99         else:

RuntimeError: Trying to create tensor with negative dimension -1: [-1, 1024]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should import [XLNetForSequenceClassification](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/xlnet.html) from [transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) and not from pytorch-transformers. First, make sure transformers is installed:

```sh
> pip install transformers
```

Then, in your code:

```py
from transformers import XLNetForSequenceClassification
model = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("xlnet-large-cased", num_labels = 2)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've not changed internally anything, most likely a version mismatch. Have you upgraded any relevant modules? Go back to previous version if you have that should solve it.

[Pytorch Quantization RuntimeError: Trying to create tensor with negative dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60567538/pytorch-quantization-runtimeerror-trying-to-create-tensor-with-negative-dimensi)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm working on google colab and I didn't upgrade anything. So I'm not sure how to go about this given the link you've pointed out.